# Efficiently saving summable array values in RDBMs

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate

I have a dataset where we track engagement per-percent (so 8 people are active at 38%, 7 people are active at 39%, etc.). This gives an array with 100 values, filled with integers.

I need to store this in a postgres table. The only/major requirement is that I need to be able to sum the values for each index to form a new array. Example:

```
Row 1: [5, 3, 5, ... 7]
Row 2: [2, 5, 3, ... 1]
Sum:   [7, 8, 8, ... 8]
```

The naive way to save these would be 100 individual `(BIG)INT` columns, which would allow you to sum the values per-column over multiple rows. However, this makes the table very wide (and does not seem like the most efficient way to do it). I have looked into `(BIG)INT[100]` columns, but I cannot seem to find a good, native way to sum the values. Same thing with `json(b)` columns (with a native JSON array).

Have I overlooked something? Is there a good, efficient way to do this without completely bloating a table?

Comment: Why not a junction table with `row_id, percent, active_count`?

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `unnest() with ordinality`:

```
with the_table(intarr) as (
    values 
        (array[1, 2, 3, 4]), 
        (array[1, 2, 3, 4]), 
        (array[1, 2, 3, 4])
)

select array_agg(sum order by ordinality)
from (
    select ordinality, sum(unnest)
    from the_table,
    lateral unnest(intarr) with ordinality
    group by 1
    ) s;

 array_agg  
------------
 {3,6,9,12}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that seems to work:

```
select array_agg(sum_aval order by ind)
from (select ind, sum(aval) sum_aval
      from (select id, unnest(a) as aval, generate_series(1, 3) as ind
            from (values (1, array[1, 2, 3]), (2, array[3, 4, 5])) v(id, a)
           ) x
      group by ind
     ) x;
```

That is, unnest the arrays *and* generate indexes for them using `generate_series()`.  Then you can aggregate at the index level and then re-combine into an array (using two separate aggregations).

Comment: `generate_subscript()` may fit more than `generate_series()` -- or `unnest() with ordinality` on 9.4+